# Make a cell scroll/marquee text right to left?

Tags: excel, scroll

I have my cell M2 in Excel which contains a large amount of text. I am trying to figure out a way of making this text scroll right to left continuously.

I have done a lot of looking on the web but all I can find are codes like this which don't make any sense to me and I want to try and make this as simple as possible. Could someone please show me a simple way of getting this to do what I want.

```
Sub StartMarquee()
Dim sMarquee As String
Dim iPosition As Integer

sMarquee = "This is a scrolling Marquee"

With Me
With .tbMarquee
.Text = ""

For iPosition = 1 To Len(sMarquee)
.Text = .Text & Mid(sMarquee, iPosition, 1)
Application.Wait TimeSerial(Hour(Now()), Minute(Now()), Second(Now()) + 1)
Next iPosition
End With
End With

'Beep
'Application.OnTime Now + TimeSerial(Hour(Now()), Minute(Now()), Second(Now()) + 2), "StartMarquee"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this could be done inside of a for loop in the subroutine, the entire application is going to be locked up while the for loop is executing, which would make it extremely unhelpful.

Instead think of one run of the subroutine as a single iteration. When the sub runs you want it to detect where in the message the marquee is already at in cell M13, and then push the message one more character. That `Application.OnTime` deal will then schedule the subroutine for its next iteration.

```
Sub DoMarquee()
    Dim sMarquee As String
    Dim iWidth As Integer
    Dim iPosition As Integer
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim iCurPos As Integer

    'Set the message to be displayed in this cell
    sMarquee = "This is a scrolling Marquee."

    'Set the cell width (how many characters you want displayed at once
    iWidth = 10

    'Which cell are we doing this in?
    Set rCell = Sheet1.Range("M2")

    'determine where we are now with the message.
    '   instr will return the position of the first
    '   character where the current cell value is in
    '   the marquee message
    iCurPos = InStr(1, sMarquee, rCell.Value)

    'If we are position 0, then there is no message, so start over
    '   otherwise, bump the message to the next characterusing mid
    If iCurPos = 0 Then
        'Start it over
        rCell.Value = Mid(sMarquee, 1, iWidth)
    Else
        'bump it
        rCell.Value = Mid(sMarquee, iCurPos + 1, iWidth)
    End If

    'Set excel up to run this thing again in a second or two or whatever
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "DoMarquee"
End Sub
```

Put this into a new Module, in your VBE for the workbook and run it. If you want it to stop then comment out that last line `Application.OnTime...`

This whole subroutine will run in a flash, so the user of the workbook really shouldn't see it running each second to bump the marquee to the next character.